# Durvasa's curse on Shakuntala

Tags: mahabharata, curse, durvasa, bharata

Kalidasa details about Durvasa's curse on Shakuntala, which makes Dushyanata forget about her. But Mahabharata, in [this translation](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01075.htm), does not talk about it.
Are there any other scriptures which talk about Durvasa's curse?